# How to render a three.js project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, rendering

I follow [this](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/getting-started-with-your-first-three-js-project-part-one-the-setup-17f18660aecc) three.js beginners tutorial and I'm stuck at part 2 because nothing is rendering on my web page. I read / watched other tutorials but I'm facing the same problem everytime.

I installed three.js with the npm install three --save command and the code is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=”en”>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>My First three.js Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="./js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
import { TrackballControls } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.6, 1200);
camera.position.z = 5;

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor("#233143");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Make Canvas Responsive
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

// Create Box
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });
const boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,
    boxMaterial);
boxMesh.rotation.set(40, 0, 40);
scene.add(boxMesh);

const rendering = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(rendering);
    // Constantly rotate box
    scene.rotation.z -= 0.005;
    scene.rotation.x -= 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
rendering();
```

```
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    canvas {
        display: block;
    }
```

Something is definitely wrong, but what?

Comment: My best guess is that you're using a Lambert material without adding any lights. You're trying to render a box in a black room, leading to a black screen.

Comment: The page is completely white for now so it is not a light problem

Answer (score 1):

First always run three.js project in a live server not just by clicking index.html second keep file structure same as shown in image. [image: File structure for your project]